# Using Python module graphics.py, is it possible to change object attributes?

Tags: python, graphics

I'm learning to use John Zelle's Graphics Module graphics.py.

Once you have created an object such as a Circle, is it possible to change the circle's radius?  I see no setRadius() method, only a move() method.

So is the only way to change the size of a circle to undraw() it and create a new instance of the object?

```
receptors = []
circles = []

for i in range(MAX_ITERATIONS):
    r = Receptor()
    receptors.append(r)
    print "No receptors: ", Receptor.instances

    for j in range(Receptor.instances):
        c = Circle(receptors[j].centre, receptors[j].size)
        c.setFill('lightblue')
        circles.append(c)
        c.draw(win)

    update()
    # win.getMouse() # pause for click in window

    for j in range(Receptor.instances):
        receptors[j].grow()
        circles[j].undraw()

    # To-do:
    # do adjustments()

    del circles[:]
```

Comment: http://cs.nyu.edu/~amos/courses/computer_programming/index.php?title=John_Zelle%27s_Graphics_Module